# How to deploy a big application

Tags: deployment

I have a drupal application which is in heavy developement. I need to deploy my app. and due to long list of images my deployment directory is more than 700Mb. How to deploy this on server, keeping track that while deploying next time only changed files will be deployed.

Please gimme a simple solution.

please don't give any advanced solution. Previously i was using simple ftp file zilla. Now i m using cyberduck(as feel good) for sftp.

**EDIT**

I a using git for version maintenance.

Comment: What's wrong with FTP'ing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You can use **FTP** or **SFTP** like
   now, because you must set settings
   to upload only *new* or *changed*
   files.
2. If you want use some solution
   dedicated for this problems, you can
   use **SVN (subversion)**, you can *commit* changes
   on developer machine and do *checkout*
   on server machine and server was
   download only changed files. And you
   have in this solution version
   control, you can revert your web
   application to what version you
   want.

Comment: I totally agree with @Svisstack. I wanted to add that with applications like TourtaiseSVN (and even the Eclipse IDE with a SVN plugin) makes SVN super easy.

Comment: i am using git for version maintenance. Now how can use sftp with git?

Comment: @piemesons: If you using GIT, better choice for you is SCP protocol.

Comment: can u tell me more about t.. Any tutorial

Comment: @piemesons: this is very simple, you don't must read tutorial to do this;-) use Pageant to do authentication with certificate over ssh protocol.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **rsync**, to only upload changed files.

Alternatively, you can upload the new version to a different directory and then switch a symlink or change a configuration file, so that you change to the new version instantly.